# Adjektiv für »passiv magnetisch«

Tags: single-word-request

Heute auf Arbeit sind wir darüber gestolpert, wie man eine Material nennt, an dem Magneten zwar haften, das aber selbst nicht magnetisch ist. Es geht um folgenden Satz:

> Die Induktionskochplatte funktioniert nur mit Töpfen, die [   ] sind.

- Was sagt man hier? *Magnetisch, magnetisierbar,* einfach: *wo ein Magnet dran bleibt* oder ganz was anderes?
- Was ist der physikalische Begriff dafür?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Da nach dem physikalischen Begriff gefragt wurde, lautet die korrekte Antwort:

> Die Induktionskochplatte funktioniert nur mit Töpfen, die **entweder ferromagnetisch oder ferrimagnetisch** sind.

Da aber die wenigsten Menschen Physik studiert haben, wird das kaum jemand verstehen. Damit wenigstens ihr das versteht, habe ich weiter unten eine Erklärung der fünf Arten des Magnetismus zusammengefasst.

Tatsächlich ist es leider so, dass die deutsche Alltagssprache für die gesuchte Eigenschaft keinen genau passenden Begriff bereithält. Am ehesten stimmt noch dieser Satz mit den physikalischen Tatsachen überein:

> Die Induktionskochplatte funktioniert nur mit Töpfen, die **magnetisierbar** sind.

Das führt aber automatisch zu dem Problem, dass nun niemand weiß, welchen Topf man in einen Magneten verwanden kann und welchen nicht. Es ist auch niemandem zuzumuten, dass er/sie sich die nötige Ausrüstung anschafft um einen Topf in einen Magneten zu verwandeln und diese Prozedur tatsächlich durchführt nur um zu wissen ob der Topf auf einem Induktionsherd heiß wird. Es wäre deutlich einfacher, den Topf einfach auf den Herd zu stellen um es auszuprobieren. Vor allem: Niemand will dann einen magnetischen Topf haben den man nicht mehr vom Heizkörper losbekommt falls er da mal dranklebt.

Der folgende Satz ist definitiv falsch:

> FALSCH: Die Induktionskochplatte funktioniert nur mit Töpfen, die **magnetisch** sind.

Denn »magnetisch« heißt im Alltagsdeutsch: Die Eigenschaften eines Magneten aufweisend. Oder kurz: Ein magnetischer Gegenstand ist ein Magnet, also ein Gegenstand, mit dem ich Eisenteile anziehen kann. Aber kein Mensch hat einen Topf zuhause, der zugleich ein Magnet ist

Auch das wäre falsch:

> FALSCH: Die Induktionskochplatte funktioniert nur mit Töpfen, die **aus Eisen** sind.

Denn auch Töpfe aus Kobalt, Nickel oder aus vielen Metalllegierungen sind für Induktionsherde geeignet.

Man muss sich aber nur von dem vorgegeben Satzbau lösen, und kommt dann schnell zu einer Formulierung, die sowohl richtig als auch verständlich ist:

> BESTE LÖSUNG: Die Induktionskochplatte funktioniert nur mit Töpfen, **an denen Magnete haften bleiben**.

### Erklärung zu den fünf Arten des Magnetismus

Es gibt fünf verschiedene Arten, wie Materialien auf ein äußeres Magnetfeld reagieren:

**diamagnetisch:**
Ein diamagnetischer Stoff kann von selbst, also ohne äußeren Einfluss, kein eigenes Magnetfeld erzeugen. Bringt man ihn aber in ein Magnetfeld ein, wandert er dorthin wo das äußere Feld am schwächsten ist. Diamagnetische Stoffe werden in äußeren Magnetfeldern nämlich selbst zu schwachen Magneten, deren eigenes Feld immer genau entgegen dem äußeren ausgerichtet ist. Dadurch entsteht die schwache Abstoßung.
Die meisten Stoffe die uns umgeben und aus denen wir selbst bestehen (z.B. Wasser) sind diamagnetisch.

**paramagnetisch:**
Auch ein paramagnetischer Stoff besitzt nicht die Fähigkeit ohne Einfluss von außen ein Magnetfeld zu erzeugen. Bringt man ihn aber in ein Feld, so erzeugt er ein schwaches eigenes Feld, das aber exakt dieselbe Ausrichtung wie das äußere Feld hat. Als Folge davon bewegt sich ein paramagnetischer Stoff immer dorthin wo das äußere Feld am stärksten ist,also zum Magneten hin. Weil das eigene Feld aber sehr schwach ist, ist die Anziehungskraft auch sehr gering und im Alltag meist gar nicht erkennbar.
Zu dieser Gruppe gehören einige Metalle mit denen man im Alltag selten zu tun hat, aber auch der Sauerstoff aus der Luft.

**ferromagnetisch:** (beachte das »o« zwischen »ferr« und »magnetisch«)
Das sind Stoffe, bei denen die einzelnen Atome ein sehr starkes Magnetfeld haben. Dazu gehören Eisen (lateinisch »ferrum«, daher der Name »Ferromagnetismus«) sowie Kobalt und Nickel. Im Normalfall sind in diesen Materialien die vielen einzelnen Atom-Magnete mehr oder weniger zufällig ausgerichtet, so dass sich deren Magnetfelder gegenseitig abschwächen und aufheben. Daher kleben z.B. Eisen-Nägel und Bratpfannen aus Gusseisen nicht aufgrund magnetischer Effekte zusammen.

Bringt man so einen Stoff aber in ein äußeres Magnetfeld, dann richten sich die kleinen Atom-Magnete nach dem äußeren Feld aus. Und dann heben sich die vielen Atom-Magnetfelder nicht mehr gegenseitig auf, sondern machen den ganzen Stoff zu einem Magneten, der gleich ausgerichtet ist wie das äußere Feld. Dadurch kommt es zu der bekannten starken Anziehungskraft, die stärker als die Schwerkraft werden kann, so dass es möglich ist z.B. Münzen die Nickel enthalten (1, 2 und 5 cent) mit einem Magneten aufzuheben.

Dass die Eisenteile selbst zu Magneten werden wenn sie an einem Magneten haften erkennt man daran, dass man ganze Ketten von Eisen-Nägeln aneinander hängen kann, und dass die Kette zerfällt sobald der erste Nagel keinen Kontakt mehr zu Magneten hat.

Verschwindet das äußere Feld, drehen sich aber nicht alle Atome wieder in den vorherigen Zustand zurück. Daher erzeugt jedes Eisenteil, das in einem Magnetfeld war, auch dann noch ein (schwächeres) Feld, wenn es keinem äußeren Feld ausgesetzt ist. Wie stark dieses verbleibende Eigenfeld ist, hängt von der Stärke des äußeren Feldes ab. Auf diese Weise wird aus einem Eisenstab, der vorher kein Magnetfeld erzeugt hat, ein Permanentmagnet.

**antiferromagnetisch:**
In einem antiferromagentischen Stoff (wie z.B. Manganoxid) haben die einzelnen Atome bzw. Moleküle zwar ebenfalls jeweils ein sehr starkes Feld, aber zwei benachbarte Atome bzw. Moleküle haben immer genau entgegengesetzte Felder, die sich gegenseitig genau aufheben. Antiferromagnetische Stoffe weisen nach außen hin also kein Magnetfeld auf. Bringt man sie in ein äußeres Feld, hat das zwar Auswirkungen auf die innere Ausrichtung der einzelnen atomaren Magnetfelder, aber sie heben sich auch in diesem Fall paarweise gegenseitig genau auf. Ein perfekt anitferromagnetisches Material bewegt sich also auch in einem sehr starken äußeren Magnetfeld weder zum Magneten hin noch von ihm weg.

**ferrimagnetisch:** (beachte das »i« zwischen »ferr« und »magnetisch«)
Eine Variante der antiferromagnetischen Eigenschaft, bei der sich die Felder zweier benachbarter Atome jedoch nur teilweise aufheben. Nach außen hin verhält sich der Stoff ähnlich wie ein ferromagnetischer, aber die Kraftwirkung ist schwächer weil es hier zwischen benachbarten Atomen immer zu einer Abschwächung (aber eben keiner vollständigen Aufhebung) kommt.

Einige keramische Stoffe und viele Metalllegierungen sind ferrimagnetisch. Auch aus solchen Materialien kann man Permanentmagnete machen. Wenn man im Handel einen Magneten kauft, wird man mit großer Wahrscheinlichkeit einen ferrimagnetischen Magneten bekommen, und keinen ferromagnetischen.

Die Mehrheit aller Magnete die Zettel an Magnettafeln festhalten und die in Lautsprechern und Elektromotoren verbaut sind bestehen nicht aus ferromagnetischem Eisen, sondern aus ferrimagnetischen Barium-Ferrit (Ein Eisen-Oxid, das chemisch mit Rost verwandt ist, aber zusätzlich auch Barium enthält). Auch die Beschichtungen auf Computerfestplatten, in denen die eigentliche Datenspeicherung geschieht, sind nicht ferromagnetisch sondern ferrimagnetisch.

Comment: `Magnetisch` heißt im Alltagsdeutsch eben nicht nur `die Eigenschaften eines Magneten habend`, sondern kann auch `ferro-/ferrimagnetisch` bedeuten. Falsch wäre es an der gefragten Stelle natürlich trotzdem.

Answer (score 7):

Zunächst einmal **etwas wissenschaftlicher Hintergrund in wissenschaftlicher Sprache**:

Die relevanten Materialien sind die *ferromagnetischen Stoffe* (Eisen, Kobalt, Nickel, diverse Legierungen, …). Dabei klassifiziert *ferromagnetisch* das grobe magnetische Verhalten des Stoffs und steht im Gegensatz zu [*paramagnetisch, diamagnetisch* und noch ein paar anderen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetismus#Magnetismus_von_Festk.C3.B6rpern)¹.

(Bezüglich der mikroskopischen Ursachen des Magnetismus und einiger anderen Eigenschaften (z. B. der Temperaturabhängigkeit des magnetischen Verhaltens) werden die Stoffe, die ich bisher und im Folgenden als *ferromagnetisch* bezeichne, weiter unterteilt in *ferr**o**-* und *ferr**i**magnetisch.* Dieser Unterschied ist aber in vielen Anwendungen nicht feststellbar (und daher erst seit 1948 bekannt) und daher wird in solchen Fällen in der Regel *ferromagnetisch* als Oberbegriff für *ferro- oder ferrimagnetisch* genutzt².)

Ferromagnetische Stoffe können nun unterschiedlich stark magnetisiert sein. Sind sie einigermaßen stark magnetisiert, sind sie das, was man allgemein *Magnet* nennt. Die Stärke der Magnetisierung kann z. B. durch Einbringen in ein Magnetfeld erhöht oder z. B. durch Erhitzen oder Erschütterung verringert werden. In jedem Fall erfahren ferromagnetische Stoffe in Magnetfeldern große Kräfte und haften also an Magneten.

Der „offizielle“ Begriff ist also *ferromagnetisch, aber nicht magnetisiert. Magnetisierbar* ist auch denkbar, könnte aber nicht das Gewünschte sein, da auch Permanentmagneten streng genommen magnetisierbar sind.

**Außerhalb der wissenschaftlichen Sprache** ist *magnetisierbar* zwar richtig, setzt aber das Wissen voraus, dass gerade diejenigen Stoffe, die an Magneten haften, magnetisierbar sind, also aus ihnen Magnete gemacht werden können.

*Magnetisch* wird wie *ferromagnetisch* benutzt, wenn es ein Material im Allgemeinen beschreibt. Der folgende Satz wäre also korrekt, setzt aber wieder ein gewisses Wissen voraus:

> Die meisten Stahlsorten sind magnetisch.

Ansonsten bedeutet *magnetisch* allerdings *magnetisiert* und man muss davon ausgehen, dass es so verstanden wird. Beim folgenden Satz würde ich z. B. in aller Regel davon ausgehen, dass der Stahlbarren magnetisiert ist (und nicht nur ferromagnetisch):

> Dieser Stahlbarren ist magnetisch.

Ich würde daher im Zweifelsfall dazu tendieren, genau zu erklären, was Sache ist.

---

¹ Jeder Stoff fällt in irgendeine dieser Klassen und damit bezeichnen diese Begriffe nicht das, was im nicht-wissenschaftlichen Kontext als *magnetisch* bezeichnet wird, z. B. ist Sauerstoff paramagnetisch.
² Zum Beispiel in vielen Ergebnissen [dieser Suche](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=mri+ferromagnetic+accident).

Comment: Das stimmt leider nicht. Induktionsherde funktionieren auch mit Töpfen, die keine ferromagnetischen Eigenschaften haben. Es geht nämlich auch mit jenen Töpfen, die ferrimagnetische Eigenschaften haben. Die Mehrzahl der geeigneten Töpfe sind nämlich gar nicht ferromagnetisch, sondern ferrimagnetisch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Stimmt, wobei allerdings gerne *ferromagnetisch* als Sammelbegriff für *ferro- oder ferrimagnetisch* genutzt wird, wenn es nicht gerade um die „mikroskopischen” Hintergründe des Magnetismus geht (was ja auch durchaus berechtigt ist, da makroskopisch kein Unterschied besteht). Die Sache wird also noch komplizierter … Mal schaun, wie man das kurz fassen kann.

Comment: HubertSchölnast hat Recht. Für die Induktions braucht der Topf kein Magnetfeld zu erzeugen, das Magnetfeld wird von der Herde erzeugt und verursacht, wenn er sich verändert (zB wegen des Wechselstroms) Wirbelströme im Topf, die wiederum Wärme erzeugen. Der Topf muss also nur elektrisch leitend sein.

Comment: @Yves: Ich vermute nicht, dass Hubert Schölnast das meinte. Außerdem ist bei den meisten Induktionsherden durchaus ferromagnetisches Material gefragt (siehe [hier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_cooking#Cookware), es ist etwas komplizierter).

Comment: Wie du schon selber erkannt hast, könnte das Adjektiv `magnetisch` eben `magnetisiert` oder `ferromagnetisch` bedeuten. Aus eben diesem Grund sollte man `magnetisch` niemals als Bezeichnung für eine konkrete *magnetische* Eigenschaft sondern lediglich für das Gesamtphänomen des Magnetismus benutzen. (So wie ich das gerade getan habe.)

Comment: @Toscho: Wieso? Es ist allgemein anerkannt, dass *magnetisch* in den meisten Zusammenhängen *ferromagnetisch und magnetisiert* bedeutet.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Dann frag mal die Menschen, ob Eisen magnetisch ist.

Comment: @Toscho: Dann geht es um ein Material im Allgemeinen, s.o., oder worauf möchtest Du hinaus?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Du kannst auch fragen, ob diese Münze dort magnetisch ist. Ich möchte darauf hinaus, dass das adjektiv `magnetisch` als konkrete Eigenschaft unklar definiert ist und deswegen nicht verwendet werden sollte.

Comment: @Toscho: Dem widerspreche ich (zumindest halb): In den meisten Fällen ist aus dem Zusammenhang ziemlich klar, wie das Wort *magnetisch* gemeint ist. Es ist zwar zugegebenermaßen unschön, dass der Zusammenhang nötig ist, aber da gibt es noch ganz andere Mehrdeutigkeiten, mit denen die Sprache klarkommt, und die Alternativen sind in der Regel auch nicht schöner.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Nenn mir bitte einen Fall, in dem aus Allgemeinbildung heraus *völlig* klar ist, was mit `magnetisch` tatsächlich gemeint ist.

Comment: @Toscho: »Magnetische Schraubenzieher sind praktisch, da einem nicht andauernd Schrauben sonstwohin fliegen.« – »Dieser Wecker ist magnetisch und haftet daher an vielen Küchengeräten.« – »Unser Mensabesteck ist leicht magnetisch.« – »In Operationssäälen mit Kernspintomographen wird Besteck aus nicht-magnetischen Materialien eingesetzt, z. B. Titan.«

Comment: @Wrzlprmft In den ersten beiden Beispielen erklärst du noch näher, was `magnetisch` jeweils bedeutet. Im dritten Beispiel weiß ich selber nicht, was du meinst. Und dass man aus Allgemeinbildung heraus beim vierten Beispiel weiß, was gemeint ist, bezweifle ich.

Answer (score 4):

Ich glaube das passende Adjektiv ist hier ferromagnetisch.

> Die Induktionskochplatte funktioniert nur mit Töpfen, die
>   ferromagnetische Eigenschaften haben.

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetismus
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induktionskochfeld

Comment: könnte man nicht einfach *..., die ferromagnetisch sind* sagen? oder klingt es so umgangssprachlich?

Comment: @c.p.: Ja, man könnte das so verkürzen, ohne dass es umgangssprachlich klänge.

Comment: Das stimmt leider nicht. Induktionsherde funktionieren auch mit Töpfen, die keine ferromagnetischen Eigenschaften haben. Es geht nämlich auch mit jenen Töpfen, die ferrimagnetische Eigenschaften haben. Die Mehrzahl der geeigneten Töpfe sind nämlich gar nicht ferromagnetisch, sondern ferrimagnetisch.